# deploying play framework application on amazon ec2 (external libs)

Tags: deployment, playframework, frameworks, playframework-2.0, libs

I am trying to deploy my play application to an instance on amazon ec2.

I have copied the project directory to the server and used 'play start'.

It is a simple app including an index page with a form with a submit button.

When I use the submit button I get a Reflection runtime exception. Caused by a null pointer exception. What is happening is the form value is not being submitted in the post request. Causing a null value to exist in my form validation.

I am guessing this is down to my deployment as the app runs perfectly on my laptop.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be to delete the /target directory in the application. Running 'play run' and this all got recompiled and worked!

Happiness!